# Removing characters inside parenthesis in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I made a program that will delete characters inside a parenthesis. The inputted text should have matching open and close parenthesis.

Case 1:

Input:    `(Hello) World`
Output: `World`

Case 2:

Input:    `(Hello World`
Output: `(Hello World`

Case 3:

Input:    `Hello)(World`
Output: `Hello)(World`

Case 4:

Input:    `Hello((hi) World)`
Output: `Hello`

Case 5:

Input:    `(Hello) hi (World)`
Output: `hi`

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    char string[100] = {0};
    char removedletters[100] = {0};
    fgets(string, 100, stdin);
    char *p;
    int x = 0;
    int b = 0;
    for (p=string; *p!=0; p++) {
        if (*(p-1) == '(' && x) {
            x = 0;
        }
        if (*p == ')') {
            x = 1;
        }
        if (!x){
            removedletters[b] = *p;
            b++;
        }
    }
    puts(removedletters);
}
```

Case 1, 3, and 5 are correct, but not in Case 2 and 4.
What's wrong with my code?

Comment: use  strchr instead of searching manually through the string

Comment: `if(*(p-1)` is undefined behavior for the first iteration.

Comment: +1 Welcome to stackoverflow! Great first question.

Comment: *(p-1) could be anything when p=string

Comment: what does your removedletters string consist of the ouput you mentioned ?

Answer (score 2):

You are invoking undefined behaviour:

```
for(p=string; *p!=0; p++){
    if(*(p-1) == '(' && x){
        x = 0;
    }
```

The first time `p++` is evaluated is at the end of the loop-block, therefore, for the first time, `*(p-1)` is pointing one left of `string`, i.e. you are doing `*(string-1)`.

Unfortunately, you lose any warranty if you have undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's specifically wrong with that code but, for efficiency, I'd keep a stack of the last found `(` characters and use that to remove portions whenever you find a `)`.

In semi-pseudocode:

```
// str is the input string, set up to and from pointers.
stacktype stack = empty-stack
char *from = str
char *to = str

// Process every character once and once only.
while *from != '\0':
    switch *from:
        // Open, transfer character and store position on stack.
        case '(':
            *to++ = *from++
            stack.push (to - 1)
            break

        // Close, get most recent '(' and adjust to for overwrite.
        //   If no most recent, just transfer as is.
        case ')':
            if stack is not empty:
                to = stack.pop()
            else:
                *to++ = *from++
            break

        // Anything else, just transfer.
        default:
            *to++ = *from++

// Terminate string at truncated position.
*to = '\0'
```

This will go through the string character by character, remembering all the `(` positions in the stack but still transferring characters.

Whenever you find a `)` character, you adjust the `to` pointer so that you start overwriting from the most recent `(` character, effectively removing everything inside and including a `(...)` section.